# How to get live video id from from youtube channel html

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

How to get live video id from YouTube channel using simple HTML dom parser or any other method rather than YouTube api?

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UC8Z-VjXBtDJTvq6aqkIskPg&autoplay=1
```

Because YouTube  api does not work to get live video id.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly i fund answer

```
 function getvideourl($chid)
 {
      $videoId = null;

// Fetch the livestream page
if($data = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream? 
channel='.$chid))
{
    // Find the video ID in there
    if(preg_match('/\'VIDEO_ID\': \"(.*?)\"/', $data, $matches))
        $videoId = $matches[1];

    else
        $videoId ="";
}
else
    throw new Exception('Couldn\'t fetch data');

$video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$videoId;


return $video_url;
}
```